# What is the IPv6 equivalent for 127.0.0.0/8

Tags: linux, iptables, ipv6, ip6tables

I am trying to set up an IP6tables firewall on Linux and I basically want to start copying my IPv4 configuration.

One of my rules simply accepts all traffic to the localhost **subnet**:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
```

I am a little puzzled though what the equivalent for IPv6 is. Is it as simple as:

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -s ::/128 -m comment --comment localhost -j ACCEPT
```

Many sources on internet explain 127.0.0.1, but I am specifically looking for the 127.0.0.0/8 equivalent and I haven't been able to find confirmation yet.

BTW I would expect the `ip6tables -vnL` counters to increment when I issue:

```
telnet -6 localhost 22
```

But that doesn't happen.

Comment: Another option would be to allow all traffic on the localhost interface via `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` which could then be duplicated in both the iptables and ip6tables rules.

Comment: @thrig: Good point, I'll try that one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost):

> IPv4 network standards reserve the entire 127.0.0.0/8 address block for loopback purposes. That means any packet sent to one of those 16,777,214 addresses (127.0.0.1 through 127.255.255.254) will be looped back. **IPv6 has just a single address, ::1.**

So for IPv6 its just `::1` or `::1/128`.